# Group management in XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

I am developing a chatting application and I want to implement Group Chatting the same. I have searched the internet for the same but I have not found even a single article or implementation regarding the same. Please suggest me any solution for the same or any respective link.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using XMPP then there is one XMPP extension that supports the group chat. Following link has more info about it:

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html

Comment: Ok Thanks Praful. Let me study it and get it implemented. Have you implemented the same?

Comment: No I have not.. just goggle it a bit and found this, so I shared thinking it might help you.. :-)

Comment: There are lots of existing implementations, both client, server, and libraries.  See: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find sample codes for multiuser chat.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html

This is easy to work with. Let me know if you want anymore clarifications. Also refer to igniterealtime community.

http://community.igniterealtime.org/index.jspa

You can follow the following extenctions.

http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/